# Load many types data mongo using spark

Tags: database, mongodb, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

i try to load 2 diffenrence type data from mongo using spark.
E.g: Field "house" in mongo have 2 document have data is arrray type(but it empty), and integer type.
I got fault Cannot cast ARRAY into a IntegerType.

Code:

```
   self.spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("mongo4XC") \
        .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", db_url_info) \
        .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", db_url_info) \
        .config("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "180s") \
        .config("spark.network.timeout", "300s") \
        .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.2') \
        .config("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", 1000) \
        .getOrCreate()

   df = self.spark_config.spark.read.format("mongo") \
                    .option("database", db_database) \
                    .option("collection", collection) \
                    .load()
```

Fault:

```
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2) (192.168.16.6 executor driver): com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException: Cannot cast ARRAY into a IntegerType (value: BsonArray{values=[]})
```

So how to config spark to load data this case.

I think get only set IntegerType to load work, but I can't do this right.
Thanks everyone!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.